# How to update table statistics in Oracle

Tags: oracle, table-statistics

Removing some records from table in Oracle, how to get statistics (e.g. NUM_ROWS, LAST_ANALYZED) updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gather them, for example

```
begin
  dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCOTT', 'EMP');
end;
/
```